# emacs color theme for OCaml

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I am using console emacs in tuareg mode to edit OCaml code. For syntax highlighting I am using the color-theme package and I am settled for some time now on the jsc-dark color theme. Sadly, the result of my OCaml editing experience is mediocre (most syntactic elements are rendered yellowish). Other color-themes I 've tried yield similar results (I actually spent the time to try out all of them). I've seen emacs screenshots on the web which use a much more variegated palette to render different parts of the OCaml language. Does anyone have a better theme or OCaml syntax highlight solution to suggest for console emacs? (not X).

Comment: The problem is your [terminal setting][] and has been well documented.

[terminal setting]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950/how-to-make-emacs-terminal-colors-the-same-as-emacs-gui-colors

Comment: well this is lame.  Convert my answer which uses full markdown to a comment which can't.  Real helpful, stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, looks helpful. Pity I can't upvote a comment.

Comment: I use `color-theme-clarity' but haven't put thought to it!

Comment: Yeah so basically the link offered above helped me solve it. Bottom line, for Emacs 23 which I use, I had to do two things:set TERM to xterm-256color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the link offered in the first comment helped me solve the issue. For Emacs 23 which I use I had to do two things only:

1. set TERM to xterm-256color
       (and verify that it works by running 'tput colors')
2. apt-get install ncurses-term

After that I was able to experience the themes in color-theme-6.6.0 for emacs much better. To test that your Emacs really sees the whole palette do a M-x list-colors-display