# How do you apply a Emacs custom color theme in console mode?

Tags: emacs, colors, console

When I load a custom color scheme (through M-x load-theme or M-x customize-theme) the results only seem to be applied when Emacs runs in a separate window:

[image: Emacs in GUI]

But when Emacs is run in a terminal with -nw, the default colors seem to be used:

[image: Emacs in terminal]
<sub>(source: [raghav at www.ocf.berkeley.edu](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~raghav/images/console.png))</sub>

I'm new to Emacs, so I don't know if this is expected behavior -- but it doesn't seem to be, since Googling turns up several people discussing using color themes in console mode. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value in TERM for your environment?  I had this problem and did "export TERM=xterm-256color" in my .bash_profile to fix it.  I see the link below in bzg's answer also makes reference to this.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting -- doing so does result in changes when different themes are selected. Unfortunately, this results in the colors being [way off](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~raghav/images/256colors.png). I suspect this may be because the theme uses colors that aren't in the standard 256 color palette; it's intended to be used by people who've redefined the 16 standard colors to the ones appropriate to the color theme (as I have).

Answer (score 9):

I am very late, but I had the same problem and I solved it adding the following line to my ~/.zshrc

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

If you are not using zsh (for example you are using bash), you must add it on your right console init file (for example ~/.bashrc)

Answer (score 4):

See this question:
[How to make Emacs terminal colors the same as Emacs GUI colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950/how-to-make-emacs-terminal-colors-the-same-as-emacs-gui-colors)

The theme in your console looks quite close to the one in the GUI, so my bet is that you will have to live with it -- or use the GUI.

Comment: I don't think the problem has to do with limitations in my terminal's color palette -- for one thing, none of the Emacs 24 color themes has any effect in the terminal, and for another, the old color-theme package did work.

Answer (score -1):

Using the following in ~/.Xresources seems to get rid of the blue background that comes after exporting TERM=xterm-256color:

```
emacs*Background: #002b36
emacs*Foreground: #839496
```